# How to acknowledge rabbitmq message manually using spring intergration

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have created bean for inbound channel with acknowledge property as manual, and chain method for publishing the output message ,

```
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="InputChannel" 
    queue-names="Input" connection-factory="connectionFactory" concurrent-consumers="1" message-converter="Converter"  
      acknowledge-mode="MANUAL" prefetch-count="5"/>

<int:chain input-channel="InputChannel" output-channel="OutputChannel">

      <int:transformer method = "transform" >
        <bean class="com.sampleconverter" />
      </int:transformer>
        <int:service-activator method="transform">
             <bean class="com.Transformer" />
        </int:service-activator>
     <int:object-to-string-transformer />
   </int:chain>
```

Can you please help me with the way to acknowledge messages processed with the manual acknowledge mode,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-ack) has dedicated paragraph on the matter:

> Setting the mode to`MANUAL` allows user code to ack the message at some other point during processing. To support this, with this mode, the endpoints provide the Channel and deliveryTag in the amqp_channel and amqp_deliveryTag headers respectively.

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "foo", outputChannel = "bar")
public Object handle(@Payload String payload, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,
        @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag) throws Exception {

    // Do some processing

    if (allOK) {
        channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);

        // perhaps do some more processing

    }
    else {
        channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, false, true);
    }
    return someResultForDownStreamProcessing;
}
```

Comment: can you please help me to where to add this method (sampleconverter, Transformer)@Artem Bilan

Comment: It depends of what your logic. If that is OK do not worry about transformer's errors, that's fully fine to acknowledge before. You even can create a new service-activator in the end of your chain to perform this acknowledgement